# How do I help mitigate log4j via haproxy on Enterprise Linux

Tags: proxy, log4j, redhat, haproxy, cve-2021-44228

Based on this [post](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/december-2021-log4shell-mitigation/), haproxy has provided mitigation acls rules that can be used to help fight against log4j attack requests getting proxied to the affected log4j apps.

In reading some of the users comments, It came to my attention that many Enterprise Linux Haproxy system out there might be running an older haproxy version 1.5 which doesn't have the `option http-buffer-request` directive. This directive is critical to any CVE you are trying to mitigate, even more so if this is your only option until you can upgrade the affected applications.

what is the easiest way to upgrade and to what version?

Answering my own question...

Haproxy 1.6 is needed, however RH provides haproxy 1.8 from the RHSCL repo

Make sure these repos are active on the system and install haproxy1.8

```
subscription-manager repos  --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms --enable=rhel-7-server-rpms --enable=rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
yum install -y rh-haproxy18.x86_64
```

cat the current config into the 1.8 cfg file and run a quick test config

```
cat /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg > /etc/opt/rh/rh-haproxy18/haproxy/haproxy.cfg 
/opt/rh/rh-haproxy18/root/usr/sbin/haproxy -c -V -f  /etc/opt/rh/rh-haproxy18/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

^ correct any warns or alert errors, In my experience, its mainly directive order or check port strings on your backend services. this is relatively simple to search the net for and correct

```
nano  /etc/opt/rh/rh-haproxy18/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

Add the ACLS Rules, use unique names if using more than one listener/frontend in the cfg so they don't overlap

```
systemctl disable --now haproxy && systemctl enable --now rh-haproxy18-haproxy
yum remove -y haproxy && yum install -y rh-haproxy18-haproxy-syspaths.x86_64
```

^ the `rh-haproxy18-haproxy-syspaths.x86_64` package replaced the haproxy service name so you do not have to update the systemctl scripts or even keepalived if you are using it to monitor `haproxy` service

I use this within keepalived which works before and after

```
killall -0 haproxy
```

Comment: I am also curious if the acls rules haproxy has provided are as accurate as they can be?

Answer (score 0):

HAProxy have blogged about this topic.

[December/2021 – CVE-2021-44228: Log4Shell Remote Code Execution Mitigation](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/december-2021-log4shell-mitigation/)